# Serenity BDD - How to reload page elements using pagefactory

Tags: serenity-bdd

i'm having a issue regarding element loading using pagefactory:

```
@Findy(id = painelDeContole) 
private WebElementFacade painelDeControleBtn;
```

The trick is,

[image: Screenshot 1]

on this menu i have to do a mouse-over action on "... mais" to open a sub-menu like this:
[image: Screenshot 2]

But when i call painelDeControleBtn.isVisible() it's return false. (Last image, second icon)
I need some way to reload the page element and truly verify if the element is visible after the mouse-over action.
I've already searched for some method to do this inside PageObject and WebElementFacade but hasn't found any.
I'd like to maintaing the usage of pagefactory if possible..

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way @FindBy loads elements, it may be present on the screen but not yet visible, or it may not wait until the element appears before returning the result. To do this reliably you will get better results with dynamic lookups, e.g.

```
$("#painelDeContole").isVisible();
```

or

```
$("#painelDeContole").waitUntilVisible();
```

Comment: It's not possible to implement a method to get the locator through reflection and reload the element instance? If it is possible and you give me a hint on where to do it inside serenity-core i'd be glad to implement it and open a pull-request :)